# Can IntelliJ run gradle task via bash.exe rather than Windows cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, git-bash, gradlew

I use IntelliJ to launch a gradle build task for my project, but it seems that IntelliJ is using the command prompt (or cmd.exe) to launch the gradle wrapper, because during my build I'm getting the error:

```
'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have git bash installed, and running `gradlew build` from my bash shell succeeds without any such errors.

**Is there a way to tell IntelliJ to use my bash executable to run gradle tasks rather than the default Windows cmd.exe?**

I tried changing the default IntelliJ terminal (File->Settings->Terminal) from cmd.exe to my bash.exe, but that didn't work.

Comment: Tangential, but why would you have shell dependent commands in a gradle task? If you write it the standard way it should work in any shell/OS.

Comment: Unfortunately it's from a library I depend on from another team. My gradle build script kicks of an `npm install`, and they have a post install script that was written apparently with linux/mac in mind. But if I could just get IntelliJ to use my bash executable, everything should work.

Comment: Its weird because I thought when I installed git-bash, I specifically selected the option that would make linux / bash commands available in the windows console.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by first opening a Git Bash, and then running IntelliJ from there. The IntelliJ terminal is then automatically set to a Bash terminal, and all of the great Bash commands are available to Gradle.

If you want the Git Bash window to close automatically after starting IntelliJ, try running this command from PowerShell:

```
& git-bash.exe -c 'cmd //c start idea64.exe'
```

Answer (score -1):

I use the Bash for Windows terminal in Intillij by setting the following as my default terminal.

```
cmd.exe "/K set LINES=9999&C:\windows\system32\bash.exe"
```